# What is the most efficient way to query on columns in belongs_to association in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails 3 app I'm trying to find records where a column in a parent association is equal is a particular string. e.g., Posts where category name = "my_category".

```
class Post
  belongs_to Category
end

class Category
  has_many Posts
end
```

Category contains a name column, and that is the only data I have available to run the search. So I can't filter directly on category_id.

What is the most efficient, Rails-y way to do this. I've tried several options that seemed like they should work, but didn't!.

```
Post.joins(:category).where('category.name'=>'my_category')
Post.joins(:category).where(:category=>{:name=>'my_category'})
Post.includes(:category).where('category.name'=>'my_category')
Post.includes(:categories).where('category.name'=>'my_category')
Post.includes(:category).where(:category=>{:name=>'my_category'})
```

I can see how to do this in two lines

```
category=Category.where(:name=>"my_category")
Post.where(:category_id=>category)
```

But I wonder if I'm overlooking some Rails magic? Sorry if it's a noob question, I'm still learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.joins(:category).where( :categories => { :name => "my_category" } )
```

Note that the argument `:categories` is plural in the WHERE part.

Comment: thanks @blackbird07! Exactly what I was looking for, a single database call. I was so close, just needed to pluralize category. These complex active record queries always confuse me. I always feel like its hit and miss, trial and error whether I get the right syntax. Do you have any rules of thumb, or useful references that might help me? Thanks once again!

Comment: Yep, feeling the pain too. I always end up looking in the rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html as well as the API documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html. Search for "joins" in the latter and you will find an example with :school and :schools

Answer (score 1):

Use the methods that the has_many relationship gives you;

Original which is incorrect as per comment

```
Category.where(:name => "my_category").posts
```

Corrected

```
Category.find_by_name("my_category").posts
```

or

```
Category.where(:name => "my_category").first.posts
```

provided you have a `category_id` column on the Post model.

Comment: This won't work because `Category.where` will not return a single, but an array of entries.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This will still result in 2 SELECT statements - one for the category and the second for the posts

Comment: Thanks john! really great answer. I've learned something new to tidy up my code. I've given the answer to blackbird because of the minimal database interaction. But thanks for helping!

Comment: totally agreed - for the most efficient query a single query always wins. Good job blackbird! :)

Answer (score 1):

@blackbird07's comment on @John Beynon's answer is right.

You should try

```
Category.find_by_name("my_category").posts
```

The find_by helpers return a single object rather than an array.

Comment: This will result in 2 select statements instead of 1 - one for the category and one for the post(s)

Comment: @edward, thanks for this. I've learned something new. I've awarded the answer to blackbird for the single database call. But thanks for helping, have an up mark.